# I am using opengl32 in QT, but when I include glut.h, a link error occurs

Tags: qt, opengl, linker-errors

```
FORMS    += mainwindow.ui
LIBS += -lopengl32 -lglut32 //(error is here, the second term)


win32:CONFIG(release, debug|release): LIBS += -LC:/ (path to some lib) -l(a good lib that is not regarding to this question)
else:win32:CONFIG(debug, debug|release): LIBS += -LC:/ (path to some lib) -l(a lib)
INCLUDEPATH += C:/(path to some directory)
DEPENDPATH += C:/(path to some directory)
```

It works fine when I just use -lopengl32 and connect my openGLWidget to my mainWindow, which means I can use all the functions from opengl library. But now I need to use a function for another h file (name it x.h here) created outside of my openglwidget.h, so I just simply inlcude `<GL/glut.h>`. It seems that QT can locate the glut.h file before I compile the whole project, in other words, the purple color of key word 'GLfloat' indicates glut.h is successfully called in my x.h. However, when I compile the project, a link problem occurs:

```
 :-1: error: LNK1181: cannot open input file 'glut32.lib'
```

I don't think I need specify the detailed path for my glut32.lib, because it is right there in my visual studio's library path. The error occurs whatever I put the -lglut32 in the qmake file or not.

Also, not just for glut32.lib, say I have another y.lib that can be run in my visual studio 2015 without any error, but still the same problem occurs when I use this y.lib in my QT project. The compiler just cannot locate the lib file correctly. The error was right same to this one I post above.

So my question can be simplified as: how should I use openGL library when it is not a widget class of the mainWindow in the QT? Thank you guys whoever gives any suggestions!

Comment: You're already using Qt, why are you trying to combine it with another application framework like GLUT?

Comment: Because I want to use the GLfloat that is declared in glut.h, which I cannot use in the x.h I defined by meself. To be clear, GLfloat can be used in the openglWidget rather than in x.h.

Comment: Which GLUT implementation are you using where it defines `GLfloat` in `glut.h` instead of using the declaration in `gl.h`?

Comment: `#include "x.h"
#include <gl/GLU.h>
//#include <QOpenGLWidget>

#pragma comment(lib, "glu32")

class OpenGLWidget : public QOpenGLWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT` Here is my current openglWidget.h, I commented the `#include <QOpenGLWidget>` and put that in my x.h, now it works fine. Thank you for answering dude.

Answer (score 0):

Alright guys, the question has been solved by just adding `#include <QOpenGLWidget>` to my x.h :)

It seems that we do not need other application framework like GLUT for QT project.